# Geometric properties of a $d$-dimensional simplex in euclidean space

Tags: geometry, reference-request, polytopes

In school we have learned about objects in $2$-space and in $3$-space, with heavy emphasizes on the properties in $2$-space. My question can be formulated as follows:

What would we have learned in school, if the geomtry lessons didn't essentially restrict to the geometry of simplices in the euclidean plane, but fully generalized these inspections for $d$-dimensional simplices?

Whereas knowledge on the geometry of a triangle is taken for granted, I admit I don't know about corresponding results for a tetrahedron, (e.g.: What is the sum of the angles between faces?) not to speak of the higher dimensional analogues.

Whereas this is elementary, I don't think this is completely trivial. Do you know articles or other resources which develop the geometric theory of $d$-simplices in the elementary way I described?

Comment: I guess the thing is that three dimensions are already vastly more complicated than two dimensions. One instance of this is [Hilbert's third problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert's_third_problem) which you might find interesting.

Comment: My note "Heron-Like Results for Tetrahedral Volume" (http://daylateanddollarshort.com/math/pdfs/heron4tet.pdf)discusses some aspects of tetrahedra --such as Laws (plural!) of Cosines for faces and dihedral angles-- that echo properties of triangles. Higher-dimensional analogues can get messy, but at least the Pythagorean Theorem is nice everywhere: for a "right-corner" $d$-simplex, the square of the content of the hypotenuse-cell is equal to the sum of the squares of the contents of the leg-cells. ($H^2 = L_1^2 + L_2^2 + \cdots + L_d^2$)

Answer (score 1):

For those who can read German there is a very recent book about tetrahedra: Elementare Tetraedergeometrie - Eine Einführung in die Raumgeometrie by Heinz Schumann.

Answer (score 0):

For a start, you could try [the Wikipedia article on tetrahedra.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tetrahedron)

Answer (score 0):

It even is possible to derive similar formulas for any regular simplex of any dimension $D$ simply as a function of this very number $D$ (assuming edge sizes as unity):

1. circumradius = $\sqrt{\frac D{2(D+1)}}$
2. inradius = $ \frac1{\sqrt{2D(D+1)}}$
3. heigth (with $d<D$ dimensional element up) = $\sqrt{\frac{D+1}{2(D+d)}}$
4. volume = $\frac1{D!}\sqrt{\frac{D+1}{2^D}}$
5. surface = $\frac{D+1}{(D-1)!}\sqrt{\frac D{2^{D-1}}}$
6. dihedral angle = $\arccos(\frac1D)$

--- rk